# How do I scope a variable so that its available to other functions in the same CFC (a CFWheels plugin)?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfwheels

I want to add a variable that can be accessed by all functions in a plugin, but I'm getting a variable undefined error. Here's my plugin:

```
component
    mixin="Controller"
{
    public any function init() {
        this.version = "1.0";
        return this;
    }

    public void function rememberMe(string secretKey="rm_#application.applicationName#") {
        this.secretKey = arguments.secretKey;
    }

    public void function setCookie(required string identifier) {
        // Create a cookie with the identifier and encrypt it using this.secretKey
        // this.secretKey is not available, though, and an error is thrown
        writeDump(this.secretKey); abort;
    }
}
```

I call the plugin from my Sessions.cfc controller:

```
component
    extends="Controller"
{
    public void function init() {
        // Call the plugin and provide a secret key
        rememberMe("mySecretKey");
    }

    public void function remember() {
            // Call the plugin function that creates a cookie / I snipped some code
            setCookie(user.id);
        }
}
```

1. When I dump `this.secretKey` inside the plugin, I get a variable undefined error. The error tells me that `this.secretKey` is not available in **Sessions.cfc** controller. But *I'm not* dumping from Sessions.cfc, I'm dumping from the plugin's CFC, as you can see. Why?
2. How can I scope `this.secretKey` in my plugin so that it can be accessed by setCookie()? So far `variables` and `this` have failed, whether I add the definitions in a function, a pseudo-constructor, or the init(). For good measure, I threw in `variables.wheels.class.rememberME`, to no avail.

Here's the error:

```
Component [controllers.Sessions] has no acessible Member with name [secretKey]
```

Comment: Please post the CFML you use that a) calls init(), and b) calls remember().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing in `init()` isn't going to work when in `production` mode. A controller's `init()` is only run on the first request for that controller because it get cached after that.

So `this.secretKey` will be set on the very first run of that controller but never for subsequent runs.

You have a few options to make this work...

I. Use the pseudo-constructor, which does run on every controller request:

```
component
    extends="Controller"
{
    // This is run on every controller request
    rememberMe("mySecretKey");

    // No longer in `init()`
    public void function init() {}

    public void function remember() {
        // Call the plugin function that creates a cookie / I snipped some code
        setCookie(user.id);
    }
}
```

II. Use a before filter to call on every request:

```
component
    extends="Controller"
{
    // No longer in `init()`
    public void function init() {
        filters(through="$rememberMe");
    }

    public void function remember() {
        // Call the plugin function that creates a cookie / I snipped some code
        setCookie(user.id);
    }

    // This is run on every request
    private function $rememberMe() {
        rememberMe("mySecretKey");
    }
}
```

III. Store the key in a persistent scope so that calling it only once from the controller's `init()` is OK.

```
component
    mixin="Controller"
{
    public any function init() {
        this.version = "1.0";
        return this;
    }

    public void function rememberMe(string secretKey="rm_#application.applicationName#") {
        application.secretKey = arguments.secretKey;
    }

    public void function setCookie(required string identifier) {
        // This should now work
        writeDump(var=application.secretKey, abort=true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I then decided to give up because securing a "remember-me" system is a pain in the ass, and it should be done using an extra db column. This makes it an awful candidate for a plugin. So, no remember-me plugin after all--shame I only realized this after I finished the damn thing. Word of the day: Research!